# How do I fix "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue?"

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I've been working through a YouTube series by Hilze Vonck on how to develop games using the SFML library.  I'm close to the end of the series and am being introduced to collision detection.  As I understand it, Vonck uses a class called "Collider" and he adds a Collider to each object he wants to check the collision of.  Long story short, the Collider functions use & references regularly, and I'll admit I don't always know quite what's going on.

So I got the error "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue."  First, I researched what this error meant.  As I understand it, I'm passing a const when the function isn't asking for a const. However, I don't know how to fix it.

Still hoping to fix the problem myself, I relearned how to pass references and how to pass pointers, but I still couldn't figure it out.

The people in the comments of the video were having the same problem.  I believe Vonck uses an older version of Visual Studio and an older version of SFML.

Edit: I've tried to trim my code a little. If I still need to cut some code out, please let me know.

Also, if you would like to see the specific video I'm referencing, it is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2iCYCLi6MU&t=442s

main.cpp (The red-squiggly-error is under player.GetCollider())

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Platform.h"

Player player(&playerTexture, sf::Vector2u(3,9), 0.3f, 100.0f);

Platform platform1(nullptr, sf::Vector2f(400.0f, 200.0f), sf::Vector2f(500.0f, 200.0f));
Platform platform2(nullptr, sf::Vector2f(400.0f, 200.0f), sf::Vector2f(500.0f, 0.0f));

player.Update(deltaTime);

platform1.GetCollider().CheckCollision(0.0f, player.GetCollider());
platform2.GetCollider().CheckCollision(0.0f, player.GetCollider());
```

Collider.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Collider
{
public:
    Collider(sf::RectangleShape& body);
    ~Collider();

    void Move(float dx, float dy) { body.move(dx, dy); }

    bool CheckCollision(float push, Collider & other );
    sf::Vector2f GetPosition() { return body.getPosition(); }
    sf::Vector2f GetHalfSize() { return body.getSize() / 2.0f; }


private:

    sf::RectangleShape& body;
};
```

Collider.cpp

```
#include "Collider.h"



Collider::Collider(sf::RectangleShape& body) :
    body(body)
{
}

bool Collider::CheckCollision(float push, Collider & other)
{
    //check collision
}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "animation.h"
#include "Collider.h"

class Player
{
public:
    Player(sf::Texture* texture, sf::Vector2u imageCount, float switchTime, float speed);
    ~Player();

public:
    void Update(float deltaTime);
    sf::Vector2f getPosition() { return body.getPosition(); }

    Collider GetCollider() { return Collider(body); }

private:
    sf::RectangleShape body;
};
```

player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(sf::Texture* texture, sf::Vector2u imageCount, float switchTime, float speed) :
    animation(texture, imageCount, switchTime)
{
}
```

Platform.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Collider.h"

class Platform
{
public:
    Platform(sf::Texture* texture, sf::Vector2f size, sf::Vector2f position);
    ~Platform();

    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    Collider GetCollider() { return Collider(body); }

private:
    sf::RectangleShape body;

};
```

Platform.cpp

```
#include "Platform.h"

Platform::Platform(sf::Texture* texture, sf::Vector2f size, sf::Vector2f position)
{
}
```

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: "I'm including the full class files"; no, you should include only a [mcve], the absolute minimum amount of code, preferably as one piece, that anyone can simply cut and paste and reproduce your error. Additionally, you did not indicate which specific file/line results in your problematic compilation error. Don't you think that if you simply indicate where the compilation error occurs, it'll be more likely that someone can simply look at the code and tell you why, instead of requiring someone to actually compile the whole thing to find where the error is, first, and only then figure it out?

Comment: I will try to cut down the code a little then.  Before the main code, I mentioned where the error was.  Is this not good enough?

Comment: It wasn't "good enough" simply due to the sheer volume of the posted information, with most of it being irrelevant. It's easier to spot the relevant bits of information, when it's pretty much all that's shown, instead of something that's scattered across a large amount of mostly irrelevant details. This is precisely the reason why stackoverflow.com's [help] explains the need for a [mcve]. The problem is now fairly obvious...

Answer (score 3):

The compilation error occurs here:

```
platform1.GetCollider().CheckCollision(0.0f, player.GetCollider());
```

`GetCollider()` returns a `Collider` object. "player.GetCollider()" part of this expression is a ***temporary*** `Collider` value. `CheckCollision` is declared thusly:

```
bool Collider::CheckCollision(float push, Collider & other)
```

C++ prohibits passing a temporary object as a non-const reference parameter. The simplest fix is to simply store the temporary object somewhere, first:

```
Collider c=player.GetCollider();

platform1.GetCollider().CheckCollision(0.0f, c);
```

The other similar calls need to be fixed too. But a more proper fix is to change the parameter to a `const` reference:

```
bool Collider::CheckCollision(float push, const Collider &other)
```

This will allow a temporary to be passed directly, for this parameter.

Note that this will require further changes to the shown code. Methods of `other` that get called from `CheckCollision`() must now be `const` class methods.

It is worth it to actually do the work to make this change, because it will teach you some fairly basic, but important concepts. Class methods generally fall into two categories: those that do not modify their class instance, and those that do. The ones that don't should be declared as `const`. This allows your compiler to catch you accidentally modifying a class instance when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks.  As you suggested, I'll work on developing my understanding of classes.